# Android webview video play inline on 4.2

Tags: android, html, video, webview, inline

I'm building an app with a WebView thats supposed to play a mp4 video inline (not fullscreen) by html5 "video" tag.

It worked on my tablet(also 4.2), but failed on another target device.

Tested with default browser, always played in fullscreen and can't play second time.

I tried changing Webview Class to [VideoEnabledWebView](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView) which says could solve most video problem,

but my webview still can't play video inline, only in fullscreen.

Then I install Chrome browser to test, Chrome could play video inline, but it's abnormal.

[test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg2wU.png)

Did anyone manage to solve it? Help would be much appreciated!